# Multiple boxplots grouped by key

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot, filter

I have some data in a CSV file that I want to use to create multiple boxplots. Every sample has an identifier "set" that denotes the membership to a certain set and I want to have one boxplot per set. It tried to use the common `discard if not` macro, but it doesn't seem to work in this case.

So far I have

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

% discard by row label
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        y filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
v,set
0.1,a
0.2,a
0.3,a
0.8,b
0.9,b
1.0,b
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
    ]
        \addplot+[boxplot]
            table [y=v, discard if not={set}{a}, col sep=comma]{data.csv};
        \addplot+[boxplot]
            table [y=v, discard if not={set}{b}, col sep=comma]{data.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

Any ideas how selecting the samples based on a column could work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. Except that you need to use the (unfortunately as of now undocumented) `/pgfplots/boxplot/data filter/.code` key. How do I know about this key?

```
less /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/tikzlibrarypgfplots.statistics.code.tex
```

Result:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

% discard by row label
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        /pgfplots/boxplot/data filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
v,set
0.1,a
0.2,a
0.3,a
0.8,b
0.9,b
1.0,b
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
    ]
        \addplot+[boxplot]
            table [y=v, discard if not={set}{a}, col sep=comma]{data.csv};
        \addplot+[boxplot]
            table [y=v, discard if not={set}{b}, col sep=comma]{data.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I think that someone should suggest to the developers of pgfplots to document this key. If you do not want to do that I will be happy to do so.

Comment: +1: As of my knowledge, the `pgfplots` manual hasn't been updated for a long time.

Comment: +1 @Schrödinger'sCat, if you provide a patch or a merge request I'll be happy to add it to the manual, but I don't think that Christian will -- in the foreseeable future -- do this ...

Comment: @StefanPinnow That's great news!

Comment: @StefanPinnow I am still unable to deal with GitHub. So I am not sure if I can provide a patch. Of course, I could come up with some TeX code that one may add to the manual. It would be very similar to what you find on p. 510-511 for the `/pgfplots/hist/data filter/.code` except of course the name will be `/pgfplots/boxplot/data filter/.code`. One may add an example very much like this one but perhaps a bit simpler.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, that's not a problem. You could also write me an email with the describing text and an example or the modified file.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Can you remind me in which file the manual sits?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, sure: The relevant file should be https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/code/ci/master/tree/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.libs.statistics.tex